# Typecasting or accessing char array to integer array in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a char array in Python, which is read from a file e.g.

```
char_array = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f]
```

how do i convert/typecast/access this to an array of integers like

```
int_array[0] = 0x03020100
int_array[1] = 0x07060504
int_array[2] = 0x0b0a0908
int_array[3] = 0x0f0e0d0c
```

similar to how one would access an array of bytes as integers in C/C++ i.e. type cast an unsigned char * to an unsigned long *.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to do something in Python in a very unidiomatic way. Maybe it would help if you'd describe the big picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this maybe:

```
>>> def toInt(arr, idx):
...     res = 0
...     for i in xrange(4):
...       res |= (arr[idx*4 + i] << 8*i)
...     return res
... 

>>> '%08x' % toInt(char_array, 0)
'03020100'

>>> '%08x' % toInt(char_array, 1)
'07060504'
```

maybe there's a more elegant solution using `struct`?

Comment: Actually the it seems like this is what I was looking for char_array = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f'
int_array = unpack ( '4L', char_array)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but looks quite elegant:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from struct import pack_into, unpack_from

def convert(bytes):
    it = iter(bytes)
    arr = bytearray(4)
    buf = buffer(arr)
    # a grouping trick (see itertools examples)
    for group in izip_longest(*[it]*4, fillvalue=0):
        # pack 4 bytes, then unpack high-endian
        pack_into('bbbb', arr, 0, *group)            
        intval, = unpack_from('<i', buf)
        yield hex(intval)


char_array = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f]

print list(convert(char_array))
# ['0x3020100', '0x7060504', '0xb0a0908', '0xf0e0d0c']
```